# How to capture crosshair co-ordinates of a moving crosshair AFreeCharts?

Tags: android, view, charts, listener, jfreechart

I have a chartview which is basically a image view. I need to add crosshair to this. When the user touches the chart at any place I need to get the XY co-ordinates, map them to my dataset and finally update the textview with the mapped values. So when user moves the crosshair I will dynamically update the textview with the crossponding value.

I added a onTouchListener to the image and got the XY cor-ordinates but stuck with mapping the XY coordinate to my dataset (I have multiple TimeSeries inside the dataset). Also I am confused if I can use the plot.getDomainCroshairValue() & plot.geRangeCroshairValue() to get the value of the dataset.

Can anyone advise me on how to accomplish this in Android when using AFreeChart library?

```
Need to know when to use plot.handleClick(x, y, plotrendingInfo) ?
```

Thanks
Akhash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From javadoc : AFreeChart.handleClick()

```
/**
 * Handles a 'click' on the chart. AFreeChart is not a UI component, so some
 * other object (for example, {@link DemoView}) needs to capture the click
 * event and pass it onto the AFreeChart object. If you are not using
 * AFreeChart in a client application, then this method is not required.
 * 
 * @param x
 *            x-coordinate of the click (in Java2D space).
 * @param y
 *            y-coordinate of the click (in Java2D space).
 * @param info
 *            contains chart dimension and entity information (
 *            <code>null</code> not permitted).
 */

public void handleClick(int x, int y, ChartRenderingInfo info) {

    // pass the click on to the plot...
    // rely on the plot to post a plot change event and redraw the chart...
    this.plot.handleClick(x, y, info.getPlotInfo());

}
```

The View's onTouchEvent() should be implemented and the MotionEvent object provided when the touch event happens should be translated into a Afreechart's handleClick() which in turn delegates to Plot.handleClick()

XYPlot.handleClick() already has the conversion mechanism to transform the X, Y coordinated into dataset X, Y values.